# How to create a many_to_many association and German tablenames

Tags: sql, ruby, datamapper, sequel

I'm using Sequel models and I'm using German table names.

In the German language we don't put "s" on a noun for making it mean plural. I need to define the `many_to_many` table name without the English plural form.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: platzs_schichts (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

How to I set the many_to_many table name?

Comment: It's generally easier to go with the flow and let the software do what it wants, rather than fight it. Yes, it's unfortunate that the software, like most, has an English proclivity, but you can fall into a rabbit hole trying to force it to behave differently that it wants to assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the table name using the `:join_table` option

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :platz, join_table: :platz_schicht
```

[See the documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#join-table)